# What to do if there are major changes in SVN Repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm pretty new to [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) and I found commandline `svn` on my ubuntu to be more comfortable than the GUI versions.

My code is kept at an online repo. I decided to make some drastic changes in my local working copy. The changes were such that I decided to delete/move (intra folder) almost everything in the copy.

So, what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Not sure what your actual scenario is: you don't have repo copies in `svn`, you just have one repo and may have multiple *working copies*.

Comment: I meant working copy only! Phew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have branches where concurrent development is done, just using `svn move` and `svn rename` will do the trick. Try to make the changes in small increments and commit between every set of changes. Also try not to mix folder changes with changes inside the files.

If you need to merge such drastic folder structure changes while somebody is concurrently developing on a branch, you will end up in a world of pain to get it all merged together again. (it is possible, but the conflict resolution in this case will be an annoying task)

Comment: Actually I had just set up the repo online, and it is almost empty (it has just basic barebones of the structure, i.e., some folders and files). A situation arose where lot of structure changed and I had to make such big changes suddenly. `svn move` and `svn rename` will be a time consuming task. Isn't there any other possibility?

Comment: @c0da: Most operations in SVN (like `move`, `rename`, `copy`) are very cheap on the server. Most time is spent on your PC when your OS moves files around on the disk - Subversion uses a completely different approach internally which often only takes constant time.

Comment: Actually, I meant it would be a time consuming task for me to do so many `svn move` and `svn rename` commands. Any roundabout about that?

Comment: You could use drag and drop with a visual client? (like rapidsvn or something)